# Use sub properties in Expression.Parameter to build a linq expression

Tags: c#, recursion, lambda, linq-expressions

Let's say we have the following normal expression:

```
var result = SomeList.Where(item => item.Status.Description.Contains("READY"));
```

For these object:

```
public class Movie
{
    public MovieStatus Status {get; set;}
}
public class MovieStatus
{
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item.Status");
MemberExpression propExp = Expression.Property(pe, "Description");//boem! Description is not a property of T.
```

With some recursion with the `T` properties, I can get the correct `MemberExpression` and while debugging it looks ok, at the end I have this lambda expression:

> {item => item.Status.Description.Contains("READY")}

And, when applying these expressions to an `IQueryable` list, this would be the result:

> {System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Movie].Where(item => item.Status.Description.Contains("READY"))}

Looks ok, but when compiling / executing the expressions on the list, it gives me the following error:

> Additional information: variable 'item.Status' of type 'MovieStatus' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

How would I need to kind of 'chain' the `ParameterExpression`'s to get the above lambda expression?

The real code does not have these fixed variables, it's a generic implementation to be used by any object with any sub properties. The input is the property name in the normal format XX.YY, and a comparison value. It's a bit huge to post all the code, but below is a subset of that, taking away all the recursion to focus on the problem. Some results of the recursion have been hard-coded here. In addition it is not always `Contains`.

```
    public static void Test<T>(IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        string propertyName = "Status.Description";
        string value = "READY";
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        Type type = typeof(T).GetProperty("Status").PropertyType;//property name is some recursion result

        ParameterExpression peSub = Expression.Parameter(type, "item.Status");
        MemberExpression propExp = Expression.Property(peSub, "Description");
        Expression whereValue = GetValueExpression(value, type);

        //do the contains rule expression
        Type subType = type.GetProperty("Description").PropertyType;//property name is also recursion result
        MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { subType });
        Expression ruleExpression = Expression.Call(propExp, containsMethod, whereValue);

        //create source.Where([expressions])
        Type[] elementTypes = new Type[] { source.ElementType };

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> labdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(ruleExpression, new ParameterExpression[] { pe });

        //method call expression
        Expression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where",
        elementTypes, source.Expression, labdaExpression);

        source = source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression);
        source.ToList();//boom, error: Additional information: variable 'item.Status' of type 'MovieStatus' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have one parameter within in the `where` clause. Let's create that first:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string selector, string comparer, string value)
{
    var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(CreateWhereClause(target, query.Expression, selector, comparer, value));
}
```

For the parameter we need to create that clause, which is in fact a call expression, which "quotes" the actual lambda:

```
static Expression CreateWhereClause(ParameterExpression target, Expression expression, string selector, string comparer, string value)
{
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda(CreateComparison(target, selector, comparer, value), target);

    return Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Where), new[] { target.Type },
        expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));
}
```

The lambda expression should contain the actual comparison, which contains the member access on the left hand and the actual value on the right:

```
static Expression CreateComparison(ParameterExpression target, string selector, string comparer, string value)
{
    var memberAccess = CreateMemberAccess(target, selector);
    var actualValue = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));

    return Expression.Call(memberAccess, comparer, null, actualValue);
}
```

For the member access we can just chain these property expressions:

```
static Expression CreateMemberAccess(Expression target, string selector)
{
    return selector.Split('.').Aggregate(target, (t, n) => Expression.PropertyOrField(t, n));
}
```

Finally, you should be able to:

```
query.Where("Status.Description", "Contains", "READY");
```

BTW, I've just simplified [this code](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq/blob/master/src/NeinLinq/DynamicQuery.cs) to hopefully provide a corresponding answer.

Comment: Thanks! The last method did the trick indeed. Thanks for providing the source, might be useful